# Rewrite just homepage htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

how could I redirect just the homepage (base url) of my website using mod rewrite.

For example I want to rewrite

```
http://example.com/
```

to the subfolder

```
/sub/
```

silently, although all other urls should not be rewritten.

For example

```
http://example.com/test/
```

should still go to the `/test/` subfolder and not `/sub/test/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /sub/ [L]
```